# Is $dJ(V,V)=0$? where $J$ is a 1-form?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, mathematics

So is this always 0?( Where $dJ$ is the exterior derivative and $V$ a vectorial field)

\begin{align}
dJ(V,V)=\partial_jJ_i(dx^j\wedge dx^i)(V,V)=\\
\partial_j J_i (v^kdx^j(\partial_k)v^ldx^i(\partial_l)-v^ldx^j(\partial_l)v^kdx^i(\partial_k).
\end{align}

If $dx^j(\partial_k)=\delta^j_k$ then it is equal to 0 but this relation maintain for all basis? Or only for the canonical one(that is what I think)\

But as dJ is antisymmetric and (V,V) is symmetric I believe that it must be 0 for all basis

Comment: $\omega = dJ$ is a two-form and therefore is antisymmetric so $\omega(V,V)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $dx^j(\partial_k)=\delta^j_k$ then it is equal to 0 but this relation maintain for all basis?

It is always true, regardless of whether or not you use the canonical basis for the 1-forms. Observe that

$$v^kdx^j(\partial_k)v^ldx^i(\partial_l)-v^ldx^j(\partial_l)v^kdx^i(\partial_k)$$
$$=v^k v^l \big[\mathrm dx^j(\partial_k) \mathrm dx^i(\partial_l) - \mathrm dx^j(\partial_l) \mathrm dx^i(k)\big]$$

Obviously $v^k v^l$ is symmetric in $(k,l)$ while the object in square brackets is antisymmetric in $(k,l)$, so this vanishes regardless of what the $\mathrm dx^i(\partial_k)$ 's are.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful formula for the evaluation of the exterior derivative of an 1-form (J for instance):

$$dJ(u,v) = u(J(v)) - v(J(u) - J([u,v])$$

Needless to say that if $u=v$ then $dJ(u=v,v)=0$. This formula works for 1-forms. For n-forms $(n\not = 1)$ there is a more general formula.

By the way: an exterior derivative $d$ maps a 1-form into a 2-form, i.e. a local  (antisymmetric) bilinear form, which takes 2 vector fields as arguments.

A coordinate basis is not necessary for the validity of the given argument, i.e. it works also for anholonomic bases.